# No pasan datos de un archivo index.js a un otro archivo con un objeto window

Tags: javascript

Soy estudiante y comienzo a programar, les presento mi problema incluyendo el pseudo-código con mi lógica, esperando que alguien me pueda aportar porque no está leyendo la propiedad length al recorrer un string. Alparecer los parámetros no funcionan.

Este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//archivo cipher.js

      window.cipher = {
            encode: (offset, string) => {    
        //PASO 3: Iterar sobre la palabra para saber cuantas letras cifraremos
            for (let i= 0; i<(string.length); i++) {

        //PASO 3.1: Saber cuál es la posición ascci para c/letra que se recorre
               let asciiPosition = string.charCodeAt(i);
                //console.log('asciiPosition');

            /*PASO 3.2: Aplicar fórmula al texto ascci para saber cual es la nueva posición (x -65 + n) % 26 +65*/
                let enCodexString = (asciiPosition-65 + offset) %26 + 65;

            //PASO 3.3: Teniendo la posición definitiva de cifrado, transformar a alfabeto y guardarlo en una variable
            let result = String.fromCharCode(enCodexString);
                }
                return result;
            }
        };


    //archivo index.js

        //PASO 1: Obtener número de desplazamiento (offset/key/llave), guardárlo en una varible y convertirlo a entero (parseInt). (Pasarlo como parámetro al objeto window.cipher)

        const offset = document.getElementById('offset-box').value;
        //console.log(key);

        //PASO 2: Obtener la cadena/string del texto a cifrar y convertirlo a mayúscula.(Pasarlo como parámetro al objeto window.cipher)
        let string = document.getElementById('decodex-string').value;
        //console.log(codexString);

        //PASO 4: Imprimir resultado en el input correspondiente
        //document.getElementById(encodex-string).value.innerHTML= window.cipher.encode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues parece que *string* en la línea 12 de cipher.js es **null**. La llamada que tienes:

```
window.cipher.encode();
```

No envía parámetros a la función **encode** y esta sí que espera parámetros, mira la firma:

```
 encode: (offset, string) =>...
```

Así que debes poner los parámetros necesarios, que son dos.

Saludos.

Comment: Mucha razón, pasé los parametros y lo corregí invocando dentro del un evento click:
const buttonCifrar = document.getElementById('button-cifrar');

buttonCifrar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let offsetKey = document.getElementById('offset-box');
    let encodeString = document.getElementById('encode-string');
//Imprimir resultado en el input correspondiente en HTML//AQUÍ 
    document.getElementById('decode-string').value = window.cipher.encode(offsetKey.value, encodeString.value);    
});

Comment: Me alegro de haberte sido útil ;-)

Answer (score 1):

La variable '*result*' la estás machacando en cada iteración del bucle for, así que dicha variable contendrá la operación sobre el último caracter de la cadena '*string*'. Además, esa variable la estás definiendo a nivel de bloque, por lo que no exite fuera de dicho bloque.

Prueba esto:

```
window.cipher = {
    encode: (offset, string) => {
        let result;

        //PASO 3: Iterar sobre la palabra para saber cuantas letras cifraremos
        for (let i= 0; i<(string.length); i++) {
            //PASO 3.1: Saber cuál es la posición ascci para c/letra que se recorre
            let asciiPosition = string.charCodeAt(i);
            //console.log('asciiPosition');

            /*PASO 3.2: Aplicar fórmula al texto ascci para saber cual es la nueva posición (x -65 + n) % 26 +65*/
            let enCodexString = (asciiPosition-65 + offset) %26 + 65;

            //PASO 3.3: Teniendo la posición definitiva de cifrado, transformar a alfabeto y guardarlo en una variable
            result = String.fromCharCode(enCodexString);
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Gracias! Pude resolverlo y me ayudó tu respuesta.